# Помогите проверить поле input email

Tags: javascript, email, input

Есть мой код который просто проверяет заполнено ли поле

```
var str = $('#contact_form input[name=email]').val();
str = jQuery.trim(str);                
    if(str.length < 1){                
        swal("Ошибка!", "Вы не ввели свой e-mail!", "error")          
        return false;
    }
```

А так же нашел такой код

```
var r = /^\w+@\w+\.\w{2,4}$/i;
if (!r.test(document.forma.email.value) {
    //Код, если неверный e-mail
}
```

Но мои занания не позволяют соединить эти два код что бы получилось и проверка на то что поле не пустое и проверка что введен имено e-mail

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Проверять email какой-то [сложной регуляркой](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) — задача пустая. Не все сайты, предоставляющие ящики, следуют RFC, домены бывают разные, никто не мешает иметь `me@1.2.3.4` для личных целей.

Если корректная почта обязательна, отправь письмо с ссылкой подтверждения. (Но и тут никак не застраховаться от 10minutemail и ему подобных финтов.)

Так что при регистрации, на мой вкус, достаточно проверить наличие строки минимально похожей на адрес:

```js
const str = $('#contact_form input[name=email]').val().trim();
const correct = str.length >= 6    // минимальная длина для точки, собаки, домена + по букве между ними 
           && str.includes('@')    // есть собака
           && str.includes('.');   // есть точка
```

Comment: Пожалуйста а ты не мог бы написать свой код так что бы я его вставил просто потому что я та же не знаю куда в твой код вставить то что было в моем коде
    swal("Ошибка!", "Вы не ввели свой e-mail!", "error")          
        return false;

Comment: @МихаилВолков поменяй условие `if (str.length < 1) {…}` на `if (!correct) {…}`, а перед ним вставь код в ответе.

Comment: Спасибо за хороший пример! Но может быть длину стоит увеличить до 7? Например, адрес "@ya.ru" - пройдет валидацию, что не корректно.

Answer (score 1):

Для проверки поля не нужен ни jQuery, ни javascript:

```
<form action="demo.php">
E-mail: <input type="email" name="email" required>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Тест https://jsfiddle.net/wfmnubmr/

P.S. В Safari проверки не будет http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp

Comment: у меня работает все по другом не через стандартный способ